# Identifying Better Way to Get jQuery Menu Bar to Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have working Menubar with each buttons on Menu invoking a secondary Menbar as per below code. (Using jQuery)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#homeButton1").mouseover(function(){
        $(".secondMenu").show();
        $(".thirdMenu").hide();
        $(".fourthMenu").hide();  

     });

    $("#homeButton2").mouseover(function(){
        $(".secondMenu").hide();
        $(".thirdMenu").show();
        $(".fourthMenu").hide();  
    }); 

    $("#homeButton3").mouseover(function(){
        $(".secondMenu").hide();
        $(".thirdMenu").hide();
        $(".fourthMenu").show();  
    });
});
</script>
```

I believe its bad way of doing coding , I would rather prefer to have just one function to accomplish all this , instead of having one function for each of this menubars. I thought of the logic as below.( which includes changing the menubar ids as well)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#homeButton"+i).mouseover(function(){
        $(".menu1").hide();
        $(".menu2").hide();
        $(".menu3").hide(); 
        $(".menu"+i).show(); 

     });
     });
    </script>
```

However the issue is how do I set the value of variable "i" to reflect correct menubar. We can initialize i but we need to change it as well .My html code looks like below.

```
<div class="container">

<ul>
<li id="homeButton1">Home</li>
<li id="homeButton2">Wiki</li>
<li id="homeButton3">Jira</li>
<li id="homeButton1">Projects/Releases</li>
<li>Documentation</li>
<li>Tools/Environment</li>
<li>Help/Support</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="secondMenu">
<ul>
<li >First Sub Menu</li>
<li>Wiki</li>
<li>Jira</li>
<li>Projects/Releases</li>
<li>Documentation</li>
<li>Tools/Environment</li>
<li>Help/Support</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="thirdMenu">
<ul>
<li >Second Sub Menu</li>
<li>Wiki</li>
<li>Jira</li>
<li>Projects/Releases</li>
<li>Documentation</li>
<li>Tools/Environment</li>
<li>Help/Support</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="fourthMenu">
<ul>
<li >Third Sub Menu</li>
<li>Wiki</li>
<li>Jira</li>
<li>Projects/Releases</li>
<li>Documentation</li>
<li>Tools/Environment</li>
<li>Help/Support</li>
</ul>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why should you use jQuery for this and not just CSS3?

Html:

```
<div class="menu-1">Menu 1<ul></ul></div>
<div class="menu-2">Menu 2<ul></ul></div>
```

CSS:

```
div ul {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s;
}

div:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 2s;
}

.menu-1 ul {
    background: blue;
}

.menu-2 ul {
    background: red;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P3WUB/

Answer (score 0):

using common classes combined with either indexing or data attributes is fairly easy.

HTML using indexing, just add common class to both types of element:

```
<li id="homeButton1" class="homebtn">Home</li>
<li id="homeButton2"  class="homebtn">Wiki</li>
......
<div class="secondMenu subNav">
<div class="thirdMenu subNav">
```

JS ( using indexing):

```
var $subs=$('.subNav'),
    $homeBtn=$('.homebtn').hover(function(){
        var idx=$homeBtn.index(this);/* returns index of hovered element within collection of same class*/
        $subs.eq(idx).show(); /* show sub element with same index*/
    }, function(){
       $subs.hide() 
    });
```

**Indexing assumes that the order of nav top links to sub links is 1:1**

HTML using data attributes , common classes and ID's ( order in DOM doesn't matter):

```
<li id="homeButton1" class="homebtn" data-sub="#second">Home</li>
<li id="homeButton2"  class="homebtn"  data-sub="#third">Wiki</li>
......
<div class="secondMenu subNav" id="second">
<div class="thirdMenu subNav" id="third">
```

JS

```
var $subs=$('.subNav'),
    $homeBtn=$('.homebtn').hover(function(){
        var subId=$(this).data('sub');/* returns the jQuery selector matching subNav ID */
        $(subId).show();
    }, function(){
       $subs.hide() 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own custom attributes to the submenu trigger, and store the id of the submenu to toggle in this custom attribute. here's a brief example:

```
$(function(){
    $(".submenu-toggle").hover(function(){ 
        //mouse enter
        $(".submenu").hide();//hide all submenus
        $('#'+$(this).attr('submenu-data') +'').show();//show the submenu data target
     },
     function(){
        //mouse out(optional)
     }); 
});
</script>

<div class="container">

<ul>
<li id="homeButton1" class="submenu-toggle" submenu-data="sub1">Home</li>
<li id="homeButton2" class="submenu-toggle" submenu-data="sub2">Wiki</li>
<li id="homeButton3" class="submenu-toggle" submenu-data="sub3">Jira</li>
<li id="homeButton1" class="submenu-toggle" submenu-data="sub4">Projects/Releases</li>
<li>Documentation</li>
<li>Tools/Environment</li>
<li>Help/Support</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="sub1">
<ul>
<li >First Sub Menu</li>
<li>Wiki</li>
<li>Jira</li>
<li>Projects/Releases</li>
<li>Documentation</li>
<li>Tools/Environment</li>
<li>Help/Support</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="sub2">
<ul>
<li >Second Sub Menu</li>
<li>Wiki</li>
<li>Jira</li>
<li>Projects/Releases</li>
<li>Documentation</li>
<li>Tools/Environment</li>
<li>Help/Support</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="sub4">
<ul>
<li >Third Sub Menu</li>
<li>Wiki</li>
<li>Jira</li>
<li>Projects/Releases</li>
<li>Documentation</li>
<li>Tools/Environment</li>
<li>Help/Support</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have to hide something in the `mouseout` or user can't close open submenu when move completely away from it

Comment: @charlietfl i left that up to the OP as a learning experience. if you notice, his example doesn't close the open menu's either.

Comment: that's a simple way to say `I didn't think about that`

Comment: @charlietfl obviously i did think of it, hence the use of `hover()` with both onmouseenter and onmouseleave covered. it's an exercise best left up to the op.